# Google Visualization > Line Chart > Make grid-lines to appears in steps (rather by count)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have made a simple Line Chart:

[image]

Which is showing 4 grid-lines at points 2, 9, 16, 23, which are generated by using the code:

```
hAxis: {

  gridlines: {

    count: 4

  }

}
```

By using the above code, regardless of how much the data increase or decrease, it will always display 4 grid-lines.

Can I show grid-lines at a regular step interval. For instance, at 5, 10, 15, 20... and so on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a continuous chart, no you can't set the steps. (evil google)

Answer (score 3):

Could you set the steps indirectly by working out the count based on the step size you want?

```
var theMax = 100;
var theMin = 0;
var stepsize = 20;

hAxis: {
  gridlines: {
    count: (theMax-theMin)/stepsize /* 100/20 = 5 steps */
  },
  minValue: theMin,
  maxValue: theMax
}
```